# Module used to redirect pages to SSL

Tags: 7, commerce

Is or are there currently a module(s) that redirects users of a drupal site to enforce a SSL connection on parts of the website?

Essentially accomplish the following use case:

> A user visits a glob pattern: /cart/*, / it enforces https://
>   connection as well as redirects any images/javascript to utilize a ssl
>   connection.

Comment: there is a d7 dev version of http://drupal.org/project/securepages that might help you out

Comment: @Jimajamma, you should really write that up as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: nah, I _try_ to keep link only answers in the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is currently the canonical answer:

[Use Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages)

> This module makes sure that the user is running on a secure page when
>   they create or edit content, view user details, or administer the
>   site.

The other part of my question regarding redirecting assets on a page to a secure connection has actually be integrated into drupal core. It was previously a contrib module: http://drupal.org/project/securepages_prevent_hijack

> #D7CX: This functionality is in Drupal 7 core so this module will not be ported. Please stay tuned for the securepages port.
>
> This is an add-on to the Secure Pages module that will prevent
>   hijacked sessions from accessing SSL pages, yet still allow users to
>   stay logged in when browsing non-SSL pages.

[Drupalscout](http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/drupal-and-ssl-multiple-recipes-possible-solutions-https) looks to have a great site recipe on working with SSL's as well:

> The Secure Pages module is a relatively old module and quite popular.
>   It's goal is to only make certain pages of the site use HTTPS by using
>   two lists of urls which should either by HTTPS or not. The benefit of
>   this module is that you can use regular old HTTP for most of the site
>   and only encrypt the traffic where you really need it. By default it
>   will encrypt traffic for adding content, editing content, anything
>   related to users, and for the admin area.
>
> SSL processing is taxing on a server. Using SSL on just the most
>   important pages helps make sure that the data sent back and forth on
>   those pages is encrypted. However, the session cookie is still
>   unencrypted so a user who authenticates over HTTPS and then visits a
>   non secure page sends their sesssion identifier in the clear which
>   allows for an attacker to steal their session and login to the site
>   which gives them the access to the very data that was supposed to be
>   protected. This is largely "security theater" but it sure makes people
>   feel good.
>
> Pro: Reduces load on server compared to a full SSL solution while
>   encrypting important data transmission. Con: Doesn't protect against
>   session hijacking so data can still be compromised.